# Salesforce lightning datatable not displaying related records

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

can someone help me display the related Account.name in my lwc lightning-datatable please.

here is my js file

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Id';
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import STAGE_FIELD from 
'@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
import getAccounts from 
'@salesforce/apex/relatedNameQuery.getAccounts';
const COLUMNS = [
{ label: 'ID', fieldName: ID_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
{ label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 
ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
{ label: 'Stage', fieldName: STAGE_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 
'text' }
];
export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
columns = COLUMNS;
@wire(getAccounts)
accounts;
}
```

here is my cls file

```
public with sharing class relatedNameQuery {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getAccounts() {
    return [
        select Id, Account.name, StageName 
        from Opportunity 
        where StageName = 'Closed Won' 
    ];
}
}
```

here is my html file

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <template if:true={accounts.data}>
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            data={accounts.data}
            columns={columns}
        >
       </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

i understand the options are using a wrapper or flattening the data but i am stuck

Comment: understood. thank you for the heads up